# Mapbox - setCenterCoordinate is deselecting annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm trying out mapbox (using the ios sdk) and I've run into a problem that I think I've narrowed down pretty far. This is my code:

```
func centerMap(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    map.setCenterCoordinate(location,
                            zoomLevel: 14,
                            animated: true)
}

func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, didDeselectAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
    dealDetails.hidden = false
}

func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MGLUserLocation?) {
    if let currentLocation = userLocation?.coordinate {
        centerMap(currentLocation)
    }
}
```

If I don't re-center the map when the user's location is updated (i.e., just commenting out the `centerMap(currentLocation)` call) then the annotation remains selected. Re-centering the map calls the `didDeselectAnnotation` function, and I can't figure out how to keep that annotation selected. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way around that if you update the center coordinate. You'd have to re-select the annotation. However, you probably don't need to do that. If you set the `userTrackingMode` on the map view to `.Follow`, it should re-center automatically.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help, this was the behavior I wanted all along.